# Unable to signup in Google plus Android in release apk

Tags: android

I am unable to signup in google plus in my android application. It is working fine in jelly bean and kitkat. It is not working in lollypop and above.

I am getting false in GoogleSignInResult result.success().

Below is my Code:

```
public class SignUp extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {




    private ImageView google_button
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build();


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        //initializes view
        initializeViews();


        //facebook login end


        google_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            Log.e("data g+", result.toString());
            handleSignInResult(result);

        }


    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {


        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Log.e("authType", "googlePlus");
            Log.e("authId", acct.getId());
            Log.e("firstname", acct.getDisplayName());
            Log.e("middlename", acct.getDisplayName());
            Log.e("lastname", acct.getDisplayName());
            Log.e("userpic", acct.getPhotoUrl() + "");
            Log.e("email", acct.getEmail());

            String[] DisplayName = acct.getDisplayName().split(" ");
            String firstName = "";
            String lastName = "";
            if (DisplayName.length == 2) {
                firstName = DisplayName[0];
                lastName = DisplayName[1];
            } else {
                firstName = acct.getDisplayName();
            }

            String photoUrl = "";
            if (acct.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                photoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }

            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("authType", "googlePlus");
            data.putString("authId", acct.getId());
            data.putString("firstname", firstName);
            data.putString("middlename", "");
            data.putString("lastname", lastName);
            data.putString("userpic", photoUrl);
            data.putString("email", acct.getEmail());

            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Register.class);
            intent.putExtras(data);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.



        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


    }


    public void initializeViews() {

        register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);
        fb_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
        google_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.google_button);


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.e("connectionResult", connectionResult.toString());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.server_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```